# Python: Trying to use Scrapy, getting this error...help me makes sense of this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

When I try to import Scrapy, I get this error. Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried reinstalling and uninstalling Scrapy to no avail. I'm a relative noob. Any help is appreciated.

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Scrapy==1.0.4', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 549, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2709, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2369, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2375, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`scrapy` doesn't support python3 yet, use `virtualenv` to setup a local python2 environment.